# Manually calling destructor is not evaluated as referencing variable

Tags: c++, placement-new

Once my class doesn't have destructor defined, following code gives 
`warning C4189: 'f' : local variable is initialized but not referenced`

(`f->~Fred()` isn't recognised as referencing `f`)

Is this a bug, or is this standard behaviour?

```
struct Fred
{
    int a, b;
    //~Fred(){}
};

int main()
{
    char memory[sizeof(Fred)];

    void * place = memory;

    Fred* f = new(place)Fred();

    f->~Fred();
}
```

This code is of course meaningless (it is minimal working sample), but I get this error in real scenario when writing pool allocator and using it like

```
template <typename T>
void CallDestructor(T * t)
{
    t->~T();
}
```

I use visual studio 2013 warning level 4
I tested it on some on-line compilers without warning, but I'm not sure what is their warning level

Comment: Does this warning get triggered in both Debug and Release builds? What if the destructor actually does something?

Comment: @Banex If destructor does something, everything is fine. Once destructor (even empty one) is defined, everything is fine.

Comment: @relaxxx Well then calling an empty destructor is a no-op and it is like not calling it altogether, hence the warning. It should trigger also when you define an empty one but it is probably a compiler quirk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this a bug, or is this standard behaviour?

This particular **warning** ("local variable is initialized but not referenced") is something not required by the standard. As far as the language is concerned, initializing a local variable and then not referencing it is *perfectly legal*.

It is a sign that your code might not do what you intended it to do, though, so the compiler tries to be helpful and warn you about a questionable construct. ("*Have you forgotten something here?*") This is completely within the domain of the compiler, so it cannot be "standard behaviour" even if they tried. ;-)

Yes, the compiler *should* realize that `f->...` does constitute a referencing of `f`. So the warning is a false posititve. (Probably because the whole thing is optimized away, being a no-op.) Such things happen if you are using high warning levels.

But it's a **warning**, not an **error**. You may safely ignore it, or mask it out with `#pragma warning` (since you are working with MSVC).